# argsort on a PyTables' array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytables

I have a problem with NumPy's argsort. It creates an int64 array of the length of the input array in-memory. Since I'm working with very large arrays, this will blow the memory.

I tested NumPy's argsort with a small PyTables' carray and it gives the correct output. Now, what I want is to the sorting algorithm work with a PyTables' array directly. Is there a way to do this with standard NumPy calls or a simple hack into the NumPy internals?

I'm also open to non-NumPy alternatives - I just want to get the job done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with Pytables, I suggest you use the Table class which has sorting built in.

```
%pylab

import tables
#create description of your table
class Table_Description(tables.IsDescription):
    column_name = tables.Int64Col()   

#create hdf5 file and table
f=tables.open_file('test.h5',mode="w")
a=f.create_table("/","my_table",description=Table_Description)

# fill table
a.append(array([randint(0,99999) for i in xrange(10000)]))

#Create a full index (on disk if you use the tmp_dir parameter
a.cols.column_name.create_index(9,kind='full',tmp_dir="/tmp/")

#write changes to disc
a.flush()

#read indices that will sort the table
ind=f.root.my_table.cols.column_name.index
ind.read_indices()
```

Comment: This is very much the way to go for me. This effectively answers the question I asked so I'll mark it as such. I will always access columns in chunks and in a sequential manner (the first N sorted rows, and then the second and so on). To that end, is there a way to also have the column sorted in-place so as to avoid many read_sorted calls?

Comment: it is possible. However as far as I know, and I have been playing around with exactly that problem, you have to first create a full index and then copy the table in a sorted fashion. This however is only worth while if you do 1 write/copy and then a lot of reads from the same table. if you do not copy the full table, the access using read_sorted is accelerated using a full index. You will have to play around with parameters (chunksize, etc,...) to optimize performance for your use case.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (copying the original table). I have a 3 field, 152 Million rows dataset. It takes 15min to copy the whole thing and 1 second to load the data sequentially. It takes 13min to load the whole data with read_sort from the unsorted Table. So, for only 1 pass over the data (my use) it's not worth to do the sorted copy. FYI, I left chunksize as automatically computed.